# Using Yiic to access an action

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to use yiic to run an action that's inside a controller (protected/controllers/site.php)

```
class SiteController extends Controller {
    public function actionHello() {
     echo 'hello!';
    }
}
```

If I try to run (inside protected/ folder) `./yiic site hello` 
It says it only has the commands message, migrate, shell and webapp.

How do I call this action within the Command Line ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300788/run-yii-controller-action-on-command-line/16307238#16307238

Answer (score 1):

Short answer.  You can't :-)  You need to create Yii an override of CConsoleCommand (more info on the [Yii guide here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.console)).

Once you've done that, then you create an action (or shift your code right over to that action).

Comment: I ended up creating a command that imports the controller and calls its action, works smoothly and easily :)